# Can I extract and save background of a png image in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png

I have an image that was sent to me as a png file that I can't display here because it's for a client.

It has a background image--a design--with text and another image layered above it. I need to extract the background and use it on a web page. The .psd file is unavailable.

Can I extract the background image of this png file in photoshop and save it?

Thank you

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=remove+background+from+PNG

Comment: Hi user46531, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a PNG file is flat. The only way to get the background image without the working file is recreating the background image. You might be able to salvage some of the design if there is no image/text over parts of the background by using the pen tool or another selection method.

I think Fireworks is able to read layered PNG files if the original PNG was exported such in Fireworks. See [How to read Fireworks PNG multilayer files without Fireworks](https://superuser.com/questions/50044/how-to-read-fireworks-png-multilayer-files-without-fireworks)

> PNG files do not have layers, so Fireworks layers are stored in the
>   private chunks of the PNG files in a proprietary format which is not
>   PNG. I don't know of any program that can read them. You'll need to
>   ask the owner of these photos to convert them to flattened png
>   (mono-layer) or into another multi-layered format such as psd.
>
> Answered by **harrymc**

Comment: That's what I thought. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: More accurately, Fireworks writes valid PNG files that contain private chunks, which the PNG format specification allows, but only Fireworks understands those chunks.